# Enable Location in android from an application

Tags: android, android-location

Can you activate the location service on android from an application (user permission), even if is disabled in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. But you can check whether it is enabled and open the settings in case it is not:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean isEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  if (!isEnabled){

startActivityForResult(new   Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
 }
```

Comment: I'm reading about WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS but this work for not rooted  devices